# Keras generator Function

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I am trying to write a batch generator function so that I can train my Keras model using it but I don't know from where to start. Does anyone have some examples or tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) explains in a nice and simple way how to create a data generator which you can pass to your Keras model to train using `fit_generator()`. Two things to keep in mind about Keras generators, in order to be compatible with Tensorflow 2.x requirements:

1. Your generator should inherit from `keras.utils.Sequence`, which allows for internal parallelization of training
2. Populate the `__getitem__()` and `__len__()` methods. The first makes your generator iterable and the second returns its length using the builtin `len` command on the generator object. Both are required by Keras.